# $C^1$ process and infinite variation process

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^1(\mathcal{R}_+,\mathcal{R})$.

Could $f$ be an infinite variation process ?

Comment: if $f \in C^1$ then $f$ is of bounded variation

Comment: for example, it exists differentiable functions with infinite variation like $f(x) = x^2cos^2(\pi/x^2)$, $x\neq 0$, $f(0) = 0$, $x=0$ for $x\in[-1,1]$

Comment: there's a difference between differentiable anc $C^1$ (i.e. continuously differentiable)

Comment: Thus, could we write for an appropriate subdivision $0=t_0< ... < t_i < t_n = T$: $\sum_{i\geq 0} \mid f_{t_i}-f_{t_{i-1}}\mid \leq \sup_{t\in[0,T]}\mid f_t'\mid .T < +\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$C^1$ functions functions always have bounded variation.**

Here is the complete answer :

**continuous derivative ($C^1$ functions) implies bounded variation**

**Theorem** :  If the real function $f$ has continuous derivative on the interval  $[a,\ b]$,  then on this interval, **f is of bounded variation**.

**Proof** :
The continuous function $|f′|$ has its greatest value $M$ on the closed interval  $[a,\ b]$ :
$$|f'(x)|\leq M,\ \ \forall x\in [a,\ b] $$
Let $D$ be an arbitrary partition of $[a,\ b]$, with the points :
$$x=a < x_1 < ... < x_n = b$$
By the **mean-value theorem**, there exists on this subinterval a point $\xi_i$ such that $f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) = f'(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$. Then we get :
$$S_D=\sum_{i=1}^n\mid f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) \mid = \sum_{i=1}^n \mid f'(\xi_i) \mid (x_i-x_{i-1}) \leq M\sum (x_i-x_{i-1})=M (b-a)$$
Thus the total variation satifies :
$$\sup_D\{all\ S_D’s\}\leq M(b−a)<∞,$$

whence $f$ is of bounded variation on the interval $[a,\ b]$.

*Reference* : http://planetmath.org/continuousderivativeimpliesboundedvariation

Comment: you forgot an absolute value but yeah, this works. Could also use the formula that $V_f = \int |f'(x)| dx$ which also gives the result immediately. Anyhow I fail to see how this answer the question; this is only a proof of what I said in the comments, your question was about Ito formula and how to apply it

Comment: You rigth ! But I was really confused by the aforementioned function with infinite variation $f(x)=x^2cos^2(π/x^2)$ (etc) that I have thought that it belonged to $C^1$. But I have studied its first derivative and it is not continuous.

Comment: I have just change the name of the post for a better comprehension. Thanks ant for your contribution !

Comment: You're welcome, but you should really change the question not the "title" of the answer :-)

Comment: Right again and done !